# Calling set on VarHandle in java 14 causes UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I'm invoking the set method via reflection on the VarHandle instance

```
set.invoke(varHandle, arrayOf(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv()))
```

However I'm getting UnsatisfiedLinkError everytime and I wasn't able to find anything related to my situation.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void java.lang.invoke.VarHandle.set(java.lang.Object[])'
```

The field VarHandle points to is the **modifiers** field of **Field** class

Comment: `VarHandle`’s `set` method is signature polymorphic and requires a compiler understanding how to generate a correct invocation instruction. Calling it with an array won’t work. Besides that, what are you trying to do? Not only hacking into an internal field, but hacking it so often that you think, optimizing the access with a `VarHandle` is required?

Comment: I need to change final variable and according to various circumstances I think it would be easier to achieve it with reflection than dealing with multiple jdk versions (since I need it to be compatible with java 8 too)

Comment: Since there is no `VarHandle` in Java 8, “I need it to be compatible with java 8” can’t be the reason for using `VarHandle`.

Comment: It must be compatible with both java 8+

Comment: Solved by using jdk 9 and compiling for 1.8

Comment: Code trying to use a class that isn’t present, will still fail, regardless of which target you specified.

Comment: Sure I added a check for the java version

Comment: There’s still the information missing, why the Java 8 compatible code can’t be used with Java 9 or why the Java 9 version has to use a `VarHandle` instead of one of the other alternatives for reflective manipulation. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: java 9 is fine, but since java 12 it's not possible to access Field fields

Comment: This still doesn’t explain why you think you have to do this hack.

Comment: All I need is to change the final field, there's no any other way around. I'm injecting my wrapper class to change the behavior.

Comment: So…you want to inject a wrapper class into another or something like that. Now, add information about the involved classes and the actual field you want to modify, and you have asked a real question.